# Laravel dynamically set table name in model

Tags: laravel-5.3

I want to do horizontal partitioning for the "users" table which is having a large number of rows. So I split the table and will have then users_1, users_2 etc. These tables are generated dynamically.

My issue is how to set the table name dynamically in laravel models. I have tried below option and it works fine.

```
$hash = 1;
$user = new User();
$user->setTable('users_'. $hash);
$user->where('id', 23)->get();
```

Here I get the result from the users_1 table;
But when I call

```
User::all();
```

It is using the table users and not users_1.

I have also tried by using setTable()  in the __construct method of model. But the issue is $hash is calculated based on the value used in controller which is not getting in the construct method of model.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 9):

You can make a scope that switches the "from" part of the query builder

add this in the model -

```
public function scopeFromTable($query, $tableName) 
{
    $query->from($tableName);
}
```

Then use

```
$DynamicTableData = ModelName::fromTable($tableName)->get();
```

you can use all Eloquent methods by this approach

Answer (score 1):

It is due to `User::all()` is called statically getting a new Model class object and looking for table users by default. If you can use the instance you have created $this with `setTable()` then you can call with dynamic table names. $this refers the member variables and function for a particular instance.

Best solution for your case, would be to use the database level partitioning. So you don't need to manage the hashing. Just give a partitioning key static or range, with created_at field and then you can call to a single table with `User::all()` to get all the users and no need to call dynamically. Or can checkout database shard.

Comment: The explanation about `User::all()` being called statically explains everything. Using the get method does exactly what is needed like example below. `$model=new User; $model->setTable('new_table'); $model->get();` it returns everything from `new_table`

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help you:

```
$data = new Model;
$data->setTable('users');
dump($data->get());
$data->setTable('users_status');
dump($data->get());
die;
```

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks Gautam. I have tried this and it works. But we need to query using the Model Object, like $data->select ....In this method we cannot query using Model Facade for eg: Model::select wont work as it look for users table